Factoring a weighted homogeneous polynomial?
Let $f$ be in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,.., x_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial. I know that any factor of $f$ is also homogeneous. I was wondering if this remains the case for weighted homogeneous polynomials? I was interested polynomials of the shape
$$
f = \sum_{ D =  w i_1 + i_2 + ... + i_n  } a_{i_1,..., i_n} x_1^{i_1} ... x_n^{i_n}. 
$$
Do the factors of $f$ also be weighted homogeneous in the same way? Thank you!

Replace $x_1$ with $y_1^{w}$ (or $x_1$ with $y_1^{w_1}$, $x_2$ with $y_2^{w_2}$, and so on) and the resulting polynomial is homogeneous.  So any factor is homogeneous in the $y_i$, but may require radicals to translate back to the $x_i$ (which isn't so scary in $\Bbb{C}$).

If someone could provide the details in the answer, to not  waste the bounty it would be appreciated!

This is a general fact about graded rings.
Lemma. Let $R$ be a $\mathbb N_0$-graded integral domain. If $f \in R$ is homogeneous, and $f=g\cdot h$, then $g$ and $h$ are homogeneous.
Proof. Set $k = \deg f, \ell = \deg g$ and $m = \deg h$. Clearly, as $R$ is an integral domain,
$$k = \ell + m.$$
Now write
$$g = g_\ell + g_{\ell-1} + \dotsc + g_{\ell_0} \quad \text{and} \quad h = h_m + h_{m-1} + \dotsc +h_{m_0},$$
where $g_n, h_n \in R_n$ are the homogeneous components, and $\ell_0, m_0$ are such that $g_{\ell_0} \neq 0 \neq h_{m_0}$. Then clearly
$$f = g \cdot h = g_{\ell_0} h_{m_0} + \dotsb + g_\ell h_m.$$
Note that $(gh)_{\ell_0 + m_0} = g_{\ell_0} h_{m_0}$ and $(gh)_{\ell+m} = g_\ell h_m$ are both non-zero, since $R$ is an integral domain. Since $f$ is homogeneous, it follows that $\ell_0 + m_0 = \ell + m$, which can only be true if $\ell_0 = \ell$ and $m_0 = m$, i.e. $g$ and $h$ are homogeneous. $\square$
To apply this to your problem, not that $\mathbb C[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ can be given a grading by $\deg x_i = w_i$ for all $i$. With this, a weighted homogeneous polynomial is exactly a homogeneous element with respect to the new grading.
